# equivalent to php gzinflate() in linux

Tags: php, linux, gzip

My server is responsing with Content-type:application/binary, I am able to decode that data by removing first 10 char and last 8 char from data and passing that data to gzinflate() command of php.

But I want to do same thing using Linux shell scripting, but i am not getting how to do that, does anyone know is there any similar function to gzinflate in linux, or is there any other way to solve the problem.

Comment: You tagged the question "gzip" ­— have you tried using the `gunzip` program on the downloaded file?

Comment: BTW, `application/binary` doesn't imply gzip compression, and the "correct" content type for a generic binary file is `application/octet-stream`.

Comment: ya i have tried that with gunzip but it is giving error as :gzip: data.gz: not in gzip format

Comment: i dont know about server side implementation, but it is giving me correct output with gzinflate(unzips the zipped data), so i am assuming that it is in zipped format, its header shows that it is application/binary

Comment: What happens if you use gzdecode() on the whole thing, without removing any bytes?

Comment: ohk this works, Thanks for support..., so i have used gunzip directly without removing any bytes and problem has been solved

Answer (score 0):

When using gzip, gunzip or zcat in the Linux shell, you always are working on data starting with a 10 byte header. That header includes (among others) a 2 byte signature (also called "magic"), a timestamp and the compression method. There also are flags informing about an optional secondary header following the first 10 bytes.

PHP functions gzinflate() and gzdeflate() do not work with these header bytes. That's why you had to remove the first 10 bytes from your server's response.

So, in order to inflate the data you receive from your server in a Linux shell simply pass it all to gunzip or zcat without removing anything.